# Converter Dados Long Raw para BLOB ORACLE DB

Tags: oracle, tabela-banco-de-dados, conversão-de-tipo, blob, apex

Minha situação é a seguinte, possuo 2 tabelas com owners diferentes,
uma armazena as fotos dos colaboradores da empresa em formado `LONG RAW`

e no outro owner eu preciso buscar essas fotos e apresentar na tela como imagem porém para isso acontecer precisa ser em `BLOB` pois a tabela é assim;

já tentei utilizar a função `TO_BLOB()` porém não funciona.

Ao tentar fazer a conversão utilizando o `TO_BLOB()`
recebo o seguinte erro `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BINARY got LONG BINARY`

já tentei criar uma tabela intermediária como vi em outras perguntas porém me retorna erro também

Comment: Poderia adicionar o DDL das tabelas (apenas o essencial para reproduzir o problema) e explicar o que tentou fazer, com uma breve explicação do que tentou junto com o código?

Comment: Long Raw foi descontinuado , o ideal seria converter mesmo para blog , vi este asktom , mas como todo asktom é longo demais para leitura rápida https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:510622111991

Comment: já tentou o `TO_LOB`?